# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardEachAttrProcessor'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, thymeleaf

I am creating the API to get list values from DB using spring-boot.I am also using
`thymeleaf` for the first time. While running the application I get the error,

**Error during execution of**

```
processor'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardEachAttrProcessor'
```

In console -> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Iteration variable cannot be null`

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you post your HTML and your controller code?

Comment: We won't be able to help you without the HTML and code.

Comment: And assuming there is such: the complete stack trace.